# Alexandria Contextual Text Analysis with ibapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, interactive-brokers, text-analytics-api

I am using the **Interactive Brokers API** with python.  I notice in the **Trader Work Station** there is a window with news updates.  I understand how to get the news updates using the `reqMkData`.  This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54917982/how-to-obtain-news-contract-details-from-the-interactive-brokers-api) does a great job explaining that much.

My question:

Is it possible to get **Alexandria Contextual Text Analysis** (ACTA) data that appears in the **Trader Work Station**?  I did not see anything in the [documentation](http://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/news.html) about news updates.  Here is a screenshot: [image: News Window in Trader Work Station] The ACTA analysis is the far-right column labeled **Rank**.

I figured I would ask here first before I go through the process of writing a sentiment analysis myself.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I have no idea, but I hope you'll ask the question at the TWS API forum (https://groups.io/g/twsapi/topics). I'd like to know the answer myself.